# Oracle GoldenGate dblogin failed with GGSIC : no OCI environment handle created

Tags: oracle, oracle-golden-gate

I'm in trouble with OGG dblogin.

I've installed an `Oracle Server 11.2.0` on my `windows server 2012`, and I attempted to install an Oracle GoldenGate extension.

When using dblogin with ggsci to create a connection , I got this error:

```
GGSCI<XXXXX>1>dblogin userid xxx xxx
ERROR:OCI Error DPI <status = 3-DPI-003:no OCI environment handle created>.
```

Comment: Have you set `ORACLE_HOME` environment variable point to oracle client folder and also make sure that tnsname.ora present in the admin/network folder

Comment: @Popeye no, there's no `oracle client`, I have not installed it yet. I set `ORACLE_HOME` environment pointed to `ORACLE SERVER`, does that matter?